# Simultaneous fetch() within a async function, and return after all done with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I am writing a function where I want 2 fetches to shot asynchronously, however, I will wait until all fetches done before the function returns.

If I put `await` in front of each `fetch()` then these 2 fetches will be issued in order, but if I do not have `await`, the function will return before all 2 fetches are done.

I wonder if there is a standard way to accomplish this function nicely. Here is my sample code:

```
async function sendRequest() {
  fetch(url1);
  fetch(url2);

  return something;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promise all. It will run all promises asynchronously and wait till all promises are finished.

```
async function sendRequest() {
  try {
     let result = await Promise.all([
        fetch(url1);
        fetch(url2);
     ])
  } catch(err) {
     console.log(err); // TypeError: failed to fetch
  }
  console.log(result);

  return something;
}
```

Take care: If just 1 Promise fails, every other promise fails too

Comment: It should be wrapped with try...catch block or provide catch branch to hande errors.